# Array rescale integers by their size

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array of integers, and I want to change their values for their position if I would sort them by size, Currently I'm doing this:

```
var result = { 5,4,6,12,1,0 };

var order = new int[result.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < order.Length; i++)
{
    order[i] = i;
}
Array.Sort(result,order);

for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
{
    result[i] = i;
}

Array.Sort(order, result);
//output: result = { 3,2,4,5,1,0 }
```

But not only I feel this is very inefficient, but those sorts are taking about 80% of my CPU time, according to Visual Studio's profiling.
How can I make it faster?

Comment: Use a hashed tree array. http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashed_array_tree

Comment: @TimSchmelter: The goal is not to sort, but to get the index that the item would have if sorted. For example the first item gets index 3 because it is the fourth smallest value.

Comment: @Guffa exactly what I want, I just couldn't find the words to describe it

Comment: Why is it taking so much time? Are you doing this for huge arrays? Or are you doing it very often?

Comment: To put things in context, I'ts for a genetic algorithm solution for the Traveling Salesman Problem. Those arrays are the order in which the cities are visited, after combining two genomes. The gaps between indexes are because of the transformations done to the parent's genomes so they don't overlap. Its done once for every new children, which happens a lot when computing very large numbers of generations, population and cities

Comment: I believe this can be be optimized but only if you code your sorting algorythm yourself (or modify the existing one). The reason because I consider this is you need to store input's indecies while sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for starters, choosing the correct algorithm based on the input size, will always gain benefits. I am not sure if `Array.Sort` does that, most likely not.

For example: if dealing with 3-4 elements, it will be **faster** to use your own implementation of `insertion sort / hardcoded if statements`.

Secondly, if dealing with many elements(~10000), you can easily beat the performance of `Array.Sort` by 50% if you parallelize QuickSort. See `ParallelExtensions`, though, doub't that you're dealing with that many elements at once.

The problem ultimately boils down to sorting. It's highly unlikely any solution using LINQ/OrderBy will beat the native `Array.Sort` on integer array, .NET framework has few clever optimizations that cut the speed 2x down.

In order for you to improve the algorithm by 2x, you need to sort only once.

The following assumes that the keys are in the range of 0..1000:

```
int[] _indexArray = new int[1001];

public void AbitBetterImplementation(int[] array)
{
   int[] copy = array.ToArray();

   for(var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++){
        var elem = array[i];
        _indexArray[elem] = i;
    }

   Array.Sort(copy);

   for(var i = 0; i < copy.Length; i++){
     var oldIndex = _indexArray[copy[i]];
     array[oldIndex] = i;
   }

}
```

A quick benchmark:

```
Basic implementation Time Elapsed 183,2125 ms
A bit better implementation Time Elapsed 99,4912 ms
```

Comment: I came up with a similar solution (not posted). I didn't test your specific code, but mine was still slower for "small" arrays (below around 80 elements).

Comment: Was very slightly faster for smaller arrays, somewhat faster for larger arrays.

Comment: Forgot to add, it was slightly faster than my version when doing parallel processing. Without it, it was about twice as fast, like your benchmarks show

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
var order = Enumerable.Range( 0, results.Length ).OrderBy( i => results[i] ).ToArray();
```

That should give you an array such that this would print the `results` array in order without modifying the results array:

```
foreach( var index in order ) 
{
    Console.WriteLine( results[index] );
}
```

EDIT:
As pointed out the above does not provide the desired result.  However, it does provide the "inverse" of the result, so it's easy to take this and map it correctly:

```
var order = Enumerable.Range( 0, results.Length ).OrderBy( i => results[i] ).ToArray();
var indices = new int[results.Length];
for( int i = 0; i < results.Length; ++i )
{
    indices[order[i]] = i;
}
// The indices array now holds the index that each item in the results array 
// would end up at if sorted
```

Comment: This does not give the desired result. (Even when Enmerable.Range has the correct number of parameters).

Comment: Ahh, I misunderstood what the desired result was.  My approach should work to get the desired result, however with minimal modification.  I'll edit to add that.

Answer (score 0):

You can count how many lower values exist for each item:

```
int[] r = result.Select(n => result.Count(x => x < n)).ToArray();
```

or:

```
int[] r = new int[result.Length];
for (var i = 0; i < result.Length; i++) {
  int n = result[i];
  for (var j = 0; j < result.Length; j++) {
    if (result[j] < n) r[i]++;
  }
}
```

Whether this is actually more or less efficient depends on how much data there is. This is an O(n*n) solution, so it would not be as efficient if the arrays are long.

Comment: Surprisingly, it did not work faster (It took twice as long with my default parameters of 100 cities), not even with very short arrays of size 3 (50% longer)

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution written with LINQ:

```
var input = new int[] { 5, 4, 6, 12, 1, 0 };
var result = from n in input
             let order = input.OrderBy(k => k).ToList()
             select order.IndexOf(n);
```

Note that, as it is, duplicates will have the same resulting index. I don't know if it fits your needs (but I suspect duplicates are not possible in the input sequence).

Comment: No, duplicates are not possible in my input sequence. This answer, just like Guffa's, made it take twice as long too, both with short and long arrays. I suspect the additional overhead of LINQ isn't helping

Comment: @Meoiswa No, this isn't really LINQ's fault, this is sorting's. I didn't properly read your initial solution, which is obviously more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

This **sorts the array only one time** + it loops through the collection (only) 3 times. This is important, if the collection is large. It knows the orginal position if multiple values has the same value.

```
var items = new[] { 5, 4, 6, 12, 1, 0 };

var combinations = items.Select((value, originalindex) => new { value, originalindex });
var sortedCombination = combinations.OrderBy(c => c.value);
var sortedCombinationWithIndex =
    sortedCombination.Select((combination, sortedIndex) => new {combination, sortedIndex});
var result = new int[items.Length]; 
foreach (var item in sortedCombinationWithIndex)
{
    result[item.combination.originalindex] = item.sortedIndex;
}
```

Rewritten in  method that you can simply call:

```
public int[] SortIndexes<T>(T[] source) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    var combinations = source.Select((value, originalindex) => new { value, originalindex });
    var sortedCombination = combinations.OrderBy(c => c.value);
    var sortedCombinationWithIndex =
        sortedCombination.Select((combination, sortedIndex) => new { combination, sortedIndex });
    var result = new int[source.Length];
    foreach (var item in sortedCombinationWithIndex)
    {
        result[item.combination.originalindex] = item.sortedIndex;
    }
    return result;
}
```